# Tsung test can't connect by ssl with sha-256 algorithm

Tags: tsung

I faced with the error_unknown launching tsung tests. Errors have occured after changing certificate cipher algorithm from sha-1 to sha-2 on host. Maybe I need to add some extra option to the tsung configuration?

Answer (score 0):

There was an old version of Erlang that doesn't support SSL.3 with SHA-256